# Submit button replacement with image

Tags: button, replace

I have a desktop website written in php.

I have a form that has a submit button in the form of an image displaying the word "next".  When my users complete the form and click on it i want it to display the loading gif.  I have placed the necessary coding (as i understand it ) to do this but it does not replace the next image with the loading gif.   Can anyone pick up what i'm doing wrong.

relevant code section below.

```
<div class="bb"><input type="image" src="./img/next.png" alt=" Create 
My Account " onclick="ButtonClicked()"/></div>
<div class="lb"><input type="image" src="./img/loading6.gif" alt=" 
loading button "/></div>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>

</form>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function ButtonClicked()
{
document.getElementById("bb").style.display = "none"; // to undisplay
document.getElementById("lb").style.display = ""; // to display
return true;
}
var FirstLoading = true;
function RestoreSubmitButton()
{
if( FirstLoading )
{
  FirstLoading = false;
  return;
}
document.getElementById("bb").style.display = ""; // to display
document.getElementById("lb").style.display = "none"; // to undisplay
}
// To disable restoring submit button, disable or delete next line.
//document.onfocus = RestoreSubmitButton;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use class for getElementById replace class by 'id' that will work better.

Each id must be single, you cannot have many time the same id.

And use img tag rather input for picture.

And to conclude display = "" and display ="none" it's the same use display = 'block' or display = 'inline-block';

Answer (score 0):

Because there are no "**IDs**" on your HTML. You have set class names as **'bb'** and **'lb'**. Replace those classes with **id** and it will work. So change the HTML as below.

```
<div id="bb"><input type="image" src="./img/next.png" alt=" Create 
My Account " onclick="ButtonClicked()"/></div>
<div id="lb"><input type="image" src="./img/loading6.gif" alt=" 
loading button "/></div>
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>

</form>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Shehara and Jeremie ! much appreciated.

Comment: ok applied the changes.  The submit button does disappear once clicked by the loader gif does not appear ? Any thoughts ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set display to 'block' or 'inline-block':

document.getElementById("lb").style.display = "block";